# how many strings in a const char* str[]?

Tags: c++, arrays

```
const static char *g_szTestDataFiles[] = {
    ".\\TestData\\file1.txt",
    ".\\TestData\\file2.txt",
    ".\\TestData\\file3.txt",
    ".\\TestData\\file4.txt",
    ".\\TestData\\file5.txt",
    ".\\TestData\\file6.txt"    
};
```

Is there way to programmatically determine how many items is in that thing?  I could always do `#define NUM_DATA_FILES 6` or `const int NUM_DATA_FILES=6` but is there a better way?  I don't think there is, but this seems too basic and I want to make sure i'm not forgetting something . . .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Arkaitz has given you the preferred way of handling this, but as we're talking about an array of const char * here, you should be able to do the following:

```
int size = sizeof(g_szTestDataFiles) / sizeof(g_szTestDataFiles[0]);
```

Comment: Great man thanks!!  I was pretty sure there was a way to do that I just couldn't remember it lol.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 11):

```
const static char *g_szTestDataFiles[] = {
".\\TestData\\file1.txt",
".\\TestData\\file2.txt",
".\\TestData\\file3.txt",
".\\TestData\\file4.txt",
".\\TestData\\file5.txt",
".\\TestData\\file6.txt",
NULL
```

};

Now iterate one string after each other till you find NULL.

**EDIT:** Glen is right though, you should use a std::vector here rather than c style *[]

Comment: +1 for being technically correct.  Though as this is tagged C++ is it worth point out that the OP should be using idiomatic C++, i.e. std::vector instead of arrays

Answer (score 7):

You can use:

```
sizeof(g_szTestDataFiles) / sizeof(g_szTestDataFiles[0])
```

Note that this method only works if `g_szTestDataFiles` is an *array* and not a *pointer*.

Answer (score 6):

If you are indeed using C++, you might want to use a `const vector<string>` which gives you some nice abstraction and methods.

Comment: It's a good idea, but in the current version of C++, you can't declare a `const std::vector<string>()` at global scope and populate it accordingly, unless you want the vector to be empty or consist of multiple copies of one string.  C++0x fixes this and allows vector literals.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this function:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
inline std::size_t array_size(T (&)[N]) { return N; }
```

like here:

```
std::size_t sz = array_size(g_szTestDataFiles);
```

Anyway, you should follow [lhahne](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694320/how-many-strings-in-a-const-char-str/1694355#1694355) advice and use std::vector.